Почему восьМИсотый, если восЕМЬсот?
Как образуется первая часть сложного порядкового числительного?

Потому что есть разница между количеством сотен - восемь сотен - восемьсот; и порядковым номером - его номер после восьми сотен - восьмисотый.
